# How to pass an user-created array to another component?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-component

I am new to React. In fact I am new to any frontend programming lanugage. Therefore I encounter many really weird and sometimes even hilarious problems. I am struggling with sending an array to another compontent. The problem is user creates that array, and it's created dynamically inside render(){return(..)}

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.chosenItems = [];
    }

    state = {
      items: [],
    };
// code to import JSON from backend API, irrelevant, that part works fine
    
addItem(item){
     this.chosenItems.push(item);
     console.log(this.chosenItems); //logs created array, everything works like a charm
    }
render() {
      const {items} = this.state;
        return (
//some code
              <div key={item.id}>
                {item.name} {item.price}<img src = {item.url} className="photo"/><button onClick={() => this.addItem(item)}>ADD</button>
              </div>
<Basket dataFromParent = {this.getItems} />
</div>
```

and Basket class

```
class Basket extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.chosenItems = [];
    }

    state = {
        items: []
      };
    componentDidUpdate()
    {
        this.chosenItems = this.props.dataFromParent;
        console.log(this.props.dataFromParent);
    }
      
      render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <h2>{this.chosenItems}</h2>
            <h2>{this.props.dataFromParent}</h2>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
export default Basket;
```

the problem is console log shows "undefined". Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? Or maybe my entire approach is incorrect and I should look for another solution?

**Update**

```
class Home extends Component {
    state = {
      items: [],
      chosenItems []
    };
// code to import JSON from backend API, irrelevant, that part works fine
    
  addItem(item){
     this.setState(prev => ({
        chosenItems: [...prev.chosenItems, item]
     }))
    }
      render() {
        const {items, chosenItems} = this.state;
          return (
            <div>
            <div><Basket chosenItems ={this.state.chosenItems} /></div>
            <Router>
            <div className="container">
            <ul>
                <Link to="/login">login</Link>
                <Link to="/basket">basket</Link> 
            </ul>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/basket" component={Basket} />
            </div>
            </Router>
            <div>
            {items.map(item =>
              <div key={item.id}>
                {item.name} {item.price} {item.quantity} <img src = {item.url} className="photo"/><button onClick={() => this.addItem(item)}>Add!</button>
              </div>
            )}
            </div>
            </div> 
          
      );
      }
}
```

```
class Basket extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
        <div>
            {this.props.chosenItems.map(item =>
              <div key={item.id}>
                {item.name}{item.price}
              </div>
            )}

        </div>
        
        );
      }
    }
```

and that works, but the chosenItems array is printed immediatelty where

```
<Basket chosenItems ={this.state.chosenItems} />
```

is located after the button is pressed. And when I click on basket redirection I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Comment: If you are new to react id strongly advice you to start using functional components instead class components. You will end up having to use them. So it's better now than once you've gotten comfortable already with class ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you must understand that things that you don't set in state don't cause a re-render and hence an updated data isn't reflected on to the UI or passed onto the children.

Secondly, you do not need to store the data passed from parent in child again, you can directly use it from props

```
class Home extends Component {
    state = {
      items: [],
      chosenItems []
    };
// code to import JSON from backend API, irrelevant, that part works fine
    
  addItem(item){
     this.setState(prev => ({
        chosenItems: [...prev.chosenItems, item]
     }))
    }
  render() {
      const {items} = this.state;
        return (
          <div>
            //some code
            <div key={item.id}>
                {item.name} {item.price}<img src = {item.url} className="photo"/><button onClick={() => this.addItem(item)}>ADD</button>
              </div>
              <Basket chosenItems ={this.state.chosenItems} />
          /div>
       )
   }
}
```

```
class Basket extends React.Component {
      
      render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <h2>{this.props.chosenItems.map(item=> <div>{item.name}</div>)}</h2>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

 export default Basket;
```

Comment: for some reason when array consists of ids it works, but I have another problem. The array is printed where <Basket chosenItems ={this.state.chosenItems} /> is located. But when the entire object is passed the program crashes after pressing add button.

Comment: That is because, in order to render an array, you need to map over it. Updated my answer for it

Comment: Huge thanks. It worked. But there is a little problem. When I click add, the array is immediately displayed where `<Basket chosenItems ={this.state.chosenItems}` is. And when I click on route path to basket component I got: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: You haven't shown an Routes in your question above

Comment: Change route to `<Route path="/basket" render={(routeProps) => <Basket {...routeProps} chosenItems={this.state.chosenItems}/>} />`

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems in the snippet -

1. You are passing `this.getItems` to your child component as props. It's never defined in the parent. I think it should have been `items` array state that you have created.
2. `chosenItems` should have been a state and you should dig deeper on how to update a state. There is a `setState` function, learn abt it.
3. In child, again the the constructor is written like parent's with chosenItems and items which is not needed. You can use them from props.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate how to mutate the state of a component. You will find few more basics over this document.
The reason you are getting `undefined` in the log is because the `this.getItems()` in Home component is returning `undefined` either there is no such method or probably the state variable itself is `undefined`.

In a nutshell few things:

When you want to pass an array to child component, it is as simple as passing any object or property For eg. (I am hoping you want to pass the choosen items to Basket component)

Always initialise state in constructor.
so chooseItems and items should be a part of state and inside constructor.

Your code should look like:

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            chosenItems: [],
            items: [],
        }
    }
    
    addItem(item){
        this.setState({
            chosenItems: [...this.state.chosenItems, item]
        })
        console.log(this.chosenItems); //logs created array, everything works like a charm
    }

    render() {
      const {items, chooseItems} = this.state;
        return (
            items.map(item => {
                return (
                    <div key={item.id}>
                        {item.name} {item.price}<img src = {item.url} className="photo"/>
                        <button onClick={() => this.addItem(item)}>ADD</button>
                    </div>
                )
            })
            <Basket dataFromParent={chooseItems} />
            div>
        )
    }
}
```

and the Basket component would not need constructor since the required data is coming from parent component:

```
class Basket extends React.Component {
      
      render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {this.props.dataFromParent.map(item =>  <h2>{this.props.dataFromParent}</h2>)}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
export default Basket;
```